# What is the real structure of atom showing every ORBITAL

Tags: atomic-structure

Since the Bohr's atomic  model was rejected and new concept of orbital was introduced so what is the real structure of an atom showing each and every orbital?

Answer (score 1):

The quantum mechanical model of the atom is the best model of the atom so far. The quantum mechanical model can take some time to explain fully, so I will try to type a short summary.

Atoms, in terms of electrons, can be separated into energy levels. Electrons rest in the ground state, and energy can excite these electrons into higher energy levels.

Each energy level has a certain amount of sublevels. Sublevels range from s,p,d,f,g, and so on. The first energy level only has one s sublevel. The second energy level has an s and a p sublevel. The third energy level has an s,p, and d sublevel. This pattern continues theoretically forever.

Each sublevel is broken down into orbitals. An orbital always can only carry 2 electrons. The s sublevel has 1 orbital, so it can carry 2 electrons total. The p sublevel contains 3 orbitals, so it can carry 6 electrons. The d sublevel contains 5 orbitals, so it can carry 10 electrons. This pattern also continues.

To put it simply, an orbital is just a region of space where electrons are to be found in 90% of the time, and the quantum mechanical model explains orbitals in more depth. I suggest you do more research on the quantum mechanical model, so you can understand it.